# Dynamically loading content within a partial view

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Basically, I am trying to implement tabs on a main page. The tabs will consist of components on other pages for quick access. I am confused on how I can import a layout while sending data to it in a "lazy" way.

I now use the `@section` tag to bring in the layout, which is fine. But I only want to request the data it needs when the tab is clicked.

in my main.blade.php:

```html
<li>
      <a href="#tab_1" data-controller="tab_1" data-target="#tab_1" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">
      tab 1 </a>
</li>


<div class="tab-pane" id="tab_1" >
     @yield('tab_1')
</div>
```

in my tab1:

```php
@extends('main')
@section('tab_1')
@foreach ($activities as $activity)
{{--implementation--}}
@endforeach
@endsection
```

in my TabController@showtab1:

```php
public function showtab1(Request $request) {
   //Logic here
   return view('tab1', ['activities' => $activities]);
}
```

The optimal scenario is loading the content for each tab only when the tab is clicked by calling a controller function. I have gotten it to work by using routes to change the whole page, but it kind of ruins the advantage of tabs.

Comment: Can you please post your code with what you have done so that we can at least get a context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would typically implement this in such a way that you use the same layout, then pass a different parameter through your URL -> controller -> [blade include parameter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#including-sub-views) -> blade view.

The example below demonstrates how you can do 'lazy'-load (load only 1 tab at the same time) across files in Laravel:

```php
// /routes/web.php
Route::get('/tabbed-page', 'TabbedPageController@index');
Route::get('/tabbed-page/:tab', 'TabbedPageController@show');
```

```php
// /App/Http/Controllers/TabbedPageController.php

public function show($request, $tab) {
  $data = ['title'=> 'No tab'];
  if ($tab === 'tab1') { 
    $data = ['title' => 'I am tab 1'];
  }

  return view('page', [
    'tab' => $tab,
    'data'=> $data
  ]);
}
public function index($request) {
  // open tab1 by default
  redirect('/tabbed-page/tab1');
}
```

```html
{{-- /resources/views/page.php, requested at for example /tabbed-page/tab1 --}}
<nav>
  <a href="tab1" class="@if($tab === 'tab1') active @endif">Tab 1</a>
  <a href="tab2" class="@if($tab === 'tab2') active @endif">Tab 2</a>
  <a href="tab3" class="@if($tab === 'tab3') active @endif">Tab 3</a>
  <a href="tab4" class="@if($tab === 'tab4') active @endif">Tab 4</a>
</nav>
<main>
  @include($tab, $data)
</main>
```

```html
{{-- /resources/views/tab1.php, tab2.php, tab3.php, etc.. --}}
<div id="tab1">
  <h1>{{ $data['title] }}</h1>
  Content ....
</div>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I just have a couple questions.First, in the `Route::get` does the `/:tab` pass in the variable $tab to whatever is passed into the url? Secondly, is the show controller function common to all tabs? If so, where would the individual tab logic be executed? And lastly, in the page.php file, is the @include tag supposed to be a circular reference? I assumed that it would be where the specific tab content would be injected but I don't see where the logic would be to tie this include tag to the multiple of unique tab views. Thanks again

Comment: @SaileshBechar To your questions: 1) yes, you could have a URL `tabbed-page/my-lunch` then `$tab` would be `my-lunch` in the controller. 2) the show method is common to all URL's which start with `tabbed-page/anything-you-want`. 3) Right, I made a typo there; I've corrected the code now, and also added an example of how to do conditional logic in the controller.